# Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '' When the validation object contains mongo operators, you must set the modifier option to true

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-react

There is another question about the same issue, but I really couldn’t get it.

https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-fix-error-exception-while-invoking-method-actionfail-error-when-the-validation-object-contains-mongo-operators-you-must-set-the-modifier-option-to-true/53158

Could someone explain a little more about this error?

`Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '' Error: When the validation object contains mongo operators, you must set the modifier option to true`

Set `modifier option to true` … how and where that would be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the schema validation. Somehwere you use a simpl-schema library with a validation method and this schema is not created with the `modifier: true` flag, so it's expecting a document and not a modifier.

```js
import SimpleSchema from "simpl-schema";

const validationContext = new SimpleSchema({
  name: String,
}).newContext();

validationContext.validate(
  {
    $set: {
      name: 2,
    },
  },
  { modifier: true }
);

console.log(validationContext.isValid());
console.log(validationContext.validationErrors());
```

See: https://github.com/longshotlabs/simpl-schema#validate-a-mongodb-modifier

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I was able to solve the issue!